# Autofac - How to replace unit test cases constructor's parameters to use Autofac

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, autofac

I am beginner to Autofac. I have initially created a sample project and then replaced all of my new () keyword with constructor injection. Then replaced the constructor injection with Autofac and the project is working fine.

My issue:
I have my unit test cases where I pass parameters to constructors , as I had replaced my project with Autofac. I am unsure how to replace the unit test cases constructor injection to use Autofac.

```
    public class GenericHelper : IGenericHelper
    {
        private IDAL _DAL;
        private IDate _Date;

        //public GenericHelper(IDAL DAL,IDate Date)   /* Constructor injection */
        //{   _DAL = DAL;
        //    _Date = Date;
        //}

        public String CalculateMatruity(IAge AgeObj)
        {

           String Maturity = "", AgeConfiguration;

            //IDAL dalObj = _DAL;
            //IDate dateObj = _Date; 

                var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
                builder.RegisterType<AgeDAL>().As<IDAL>();
                builder.RegisterType<CurrentDate>().As<IDate>();

                using (var container = builder.Build())
                {
// AgeConfiguration = dalObj.GetMaturityConfiguration();  /* initial approach */

 AgeConfiguration = container.Resolve<IDAL>().GetMaturityConfiguration();

//Int64 Age = dateObj.Date.Year - AgeObj.Birthdate.Year;  /* initial approach */

var _d = container.Resolve<IDate>().Date.Year;

 Int64 Age = _d - AgeObj.Birthdate.Year;      /* Using autofac approach */    

 var config = AgeConfiguration.Split('|').Select(s => s.Split('=')).ToDictionary(c => c[1], c => int.Parse(c[0]));
```

............

---

My error unit tests:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestGenericHelper()
        {
            Person age = new Person();
            age.Birthdate = DateTime.Parse("1987-06-16"); 

            String expected = "Teen"; 

            DateTime FakeDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2000-01-01");
            String fake = "0=Child|13=Teen|18=Adult";

            FakeDate DateHelperObj = new FakeDate(FakeDate);
            FakeAgeDAL fakeObj = new FakeAgeDAL(fake);

            GenericHelper GenericHelperObj = new GenericHelper(fakeObj, DateHelperObj);    /* I Need to replace it use Autofac */ 

            String actual = GenericHelperObj.CalculateMatruity(age);

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
```

I need to replace the GenericHelper class instance to use autofac but call the dummy object.Can anyone please advice.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking online for `autofac unit test`? It has good docs like https://juristr.com/blog/2011/12/writing-ioc-supported-integration-tests/, or a testing framework with it built in, like Kekiri https://github.com/chris-peterson/Kekiri

Comment: @Eris,Thank you [link] https://juristr.com/blog/2011/12/writing-ioc-supported-integration-tests/ is helpful. I am still trying to learn and implement.